# ¿Son "legalización única" y "apostilla de La Haya" la misma cosa?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, lenguaje-jurídico

Quisiera confirmar si "legalización única" y "apostilla de La Haya" se refieren a la misma cosa.

> Cuando el certificado de antecedentes penales haya de surtir efectos en el extranjero, necesita ser legalizado. Debe indicarse en la solicitud el país de destino del documento ([**legalización única o apostilla de La Haya**](https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/cs/Satellite/Portal/es/ciudadanos/ciudadanos/certificado-antecedentes)).

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostilla_de_La_Haya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

España llama "[legalización](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/es/ServiciosAlCiudadano/SiEstasEnElExtranjero/Paginas/Legalizaciones.aspx)" al trámite necesario para que un documento español tenga efecto en el extranjero. Como se ve en el enlace, este trámite, por defecto, requiere la presentación del documento en la embajada española del país de destino.

Para facilitar este proceso, muchos países han firmado el Convenio de La Haya, que simplifica el proceso de legalización y lo hace uniforme, independientemente del país de origen y de destino. Para legalizar un documento expedido en un país firmante del Convenio de La Haya para que surta efecto en otro país firmante, solo es necesario poner al documento una "[apostilla de La Haya](https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/cs/Satellite/Portal/es/servicios-ciudadano/tramites-gestiones-personales/legalizacion-unica-apostilla)". Esto no se hace en las embajadas, sino en la administración del país de origen (Ministerio de Justicia en el caso de España).

A este proceso simplificado (y uniforme) de legalización basada en el convenio de La Haya, España lo llama "legalización única" o "apostilla de La Haya". Es decir: en España, estos dos términos son sinónimos.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!